# Javascript: why "this" inside the private function refers to the global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Consider the following code:

```
function A() {}    

A.prototype.go = function() {
    console.log(this); //A { go=function()}

    var f = function() {
         console.log(this);  //Window              
    };

    f();
}

var a = new A();
a.go();
```

Why does 'this' inside function 'f' refers to the global scope? Why it is not the scope of function 'A' ?

Answer (score 37):

JavaScript has a different concept of what the special name `this` refers to 
than most other programming languages do. There are exactly **five** different 
ways in which the value of `this` can be bound in the language.

#### The Global Scope

```
this;
```

When using `this` in global scope, it will simply refer to the *global* object.

#### Calling a Function

```
foo();
```

Here, `this` will again refer to the *global* object.

> **ES5 Note:** In strict mode, the global case **no longer** exists.
>   `this` will instead have the value of `undefined` in that case.

#### Calling a Method

```
test.foo();
```

In this example, `this` will refer to `test`.

#### Calling a Constructor

```
new foo();
```

A function call that is preceded by the `new` keyword acts as
a constructor. Inside the function, `this` will refer 
to a *newly created* `Object`.

#### Explicit Setting of `this`

```
function foo(a, b, c) {}

var bar = {};
foo.apply(bar, [1, 2, 3]); // array will expand to the below
foo.call(bar, 1, 2, 3); // results in a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

When using the `call` or `apply` methods of `Function.prototype`, the value of
`this` inside the called function gets **explicitly set** to the first argument 
of the corresponding function call.

As a result, in the above example the *method case* does **not** apply, and `this` 
inside of `foo` will be set to `bar`.

> **Note:** `this` **cannot** be used to refer to the object inside of an `Object`
>   literal. So `var obj = {me: this}` will **not** result in `me` referring to
>   `obj`, since `this` only gets bound by one of the five listed cases.

#### Common Pitfalls

While most of these cases make sense, the first one is to be considered another
mis-design of the language because it **never** has any practical use.

```
Foo.method = function() {
    function test() {
        // this is set to the global object
    }
    test();
}
```

A common misconception is that `this` inside of `test` refers to `Foo`; while in
fact, it **does not**.

In order to gain access to `Foo` from within `test`, it is necessary to create a 
local variable inside of `method` which refers to `Foo`.

```
Foo.method = function() {
    var that = this;
    function test() {
        // Use that instead of this here
    }
    test();
}
```

`that` is just a normal variable name, but it is commonly used for the reference to an 
outer `this`. In combination with closures, it can also 
be used to pass `this` values around.

#### Assigning Methods

Another thing that does **not** work in JavaScript is function aliasing, which is
**assigning** a method to a variable.

```
var test = someObject.methodTest;
test();
```

Due to the first case, `test` now acts like a plain function call; therefore,
`this` inside it will no longer refer to `someObject`.

While the late binding of `this` might seem like a bad idea at first, in 
fact, it is what makes prototypal inheritance work.

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.method = function() {};

function Bar() {}
Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;

new Bar().method();
```

When `method` gets called on a instance of `Bar`, `this` will now refer to that
very instance.

**Disclaimer:** Shamelessy stolen from my own resources at http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Comment: Ok, you say that it just "mis-design of the language". Does it really answers the question? Or there was some ideas behind such behavior when JS was designed? Is Hanlon's razor applicable in this case, and it really that simple?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is you are invoking `f` as a `function` and not a `method`.  When invoked as a function `this` is set to `window` during the execution of the target

```
// Method invocation.  Invoking a member (go) of an object (a).  Hence 
// inside "go" this === a
a.go();

// Function invocation. Invoking a function directly and not as a member
// of an object.  Hence inside "f" this === window
f(); 

// Function invocation. 
var example = a.go;
example();
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of all functions is `window`.

To circumvent that, you can do this:

```
function A() {}    

A.prototype.go = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self); //A { go=function()}
    var f = function() {
         console.log(self);  //A { go=function()}           
    };

    f();
}
```

Comment: The thing which is confusing me is that I've defined function _'f'_ using **var**. Am I mistaken thinking that _'f'_ will obtain the scope of the function A? Or **var** defines only that I can use this function inside the _'A'_ function?

Comment: `this` would only not refer to the window when it is in the method of a class and not just a regular function.

Comment: It is `window` **IF** you have a window. In other JavaScript contexts, `window` is not defined (NodeJS, Google's V8 engine, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Because function `f()` is not called without any object reference. Try,

```
f.apply(this);
```