# AngularJS service http success function using wrong "this" scope

Tags: http, service, angularjs

The success function of a `$http.put` doesn't have access to the `this` scope of the service it's being called inside. I need to update a property of the service in the call back from the PUT request.

This is a cut down example of what I'm trying to do in a service:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', function($routeProvider) {
// route provider stuff
}).service('CatalogueService', function($rootScope, $http) {
    // create an array as part of my catalogue
    this.items = [];

    // make a call to get some data for the catalogue
    this.add = function(id) {
        $http.put(
            $rootScope.apiURL,
            {id:id}
        ).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
             // on success push the data to the catalogue
             // when I try to access "this" - it treats it as the window
             this.items.push(data);
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry if there are some errors in the JS, the main point is how do I access the service scope from inside the success callback?

**EDIT** : while the answer to this question was correct, I switched to the `factory` method as both Josh and Mark recommended it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a closure over a variable (often called `that`) that is assigned to `this` so that your callback functions will have access to your service object:

```
app.service('CatalogueService', function($rootScope, $http) {
    var that = this;
    ...
        ).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
          that.items.push(data);
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eOA3skxTPm2K3RjrdxZo?p=preview) that uses $timeout instead of $http to demonstrate.

Comment: I still like the factory method better in this case, but +1 for actually answering the question. :-)

Comment: @Josh, I prefer the factory also.

Comment: I'm going to go with the factory answer, but I feel like I should choose this as the right answer, as it answered the question. I'll certainly add an edit to my question to mention I've resorted to your question @JoshDavidMiller

Comment: @Skeater That's totally fair. As I said, Mark *did* answer the question and I dodged it. :-)

Comment: So why does `this` refer to window instead of the service?

Comment: @mzee99, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674252/javascript-why-this-inside-the-private-function-refers-to-the-global-scope

Answer (score 23):

As far as I know, you can't. But I wouldn't try to run the service that way anyway. Here is a cleaner way:

```js
.factory('CatalogueService', function($rootScope, $http) {
  // We first define a private API for our service.

  // Private vars.
  var items = [];

  // Private methods.
  function add( id ) {
    $http.put( $rootScope.apiURL, {id:id} )
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config) { items.push(data); })
    .then(function(response) { console.log(response.data); });
  }

  function store( obj ) {
    // do stuff
  }

  function remove( obj ) {
    // do stuff
  }

  // We now return a public API for our service.
  return {
    add: add,
    store: store,
    rm: remove
  };
};
```

This is a *very common* pattern of developing services in AngularJS and it doesn't require any use of `this` in these cases.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the difference between a service and a factory, but I thought factories were supposed to `return` themselves, and services weren't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory

Comment: When I copied and pasted your code, I forgot to change it to `.factory`. I updated the answer. Services are created using one of several module methods. `factory` returns whatever you want and `service` takes just a constructor that gets run by the provider, which returns the new object. Without resorting to some JavaScript magic, you'll want to use `factory` to store results from asynchronous operations.

Comment: Ok, so I've got around the `items` issue by doing what yo've outlined above, but now I'm getting the same problem trying to call a different method from the factory in the success callback. I'm downloading some data, and if it downloads successfully I want to call a `store()` method to write that to localStorage. In your code example it'd be like calling the `get()` method for example.

Comment: You need to return a public API of a private implementation. Then you never have to call `this`. I updated the answer.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller will this work if you expose a scalar variable or array in your return object? I noticed that you only returned functions.

Comment: @Julian I'm not sure precisely what you're asking, so here's two answers: (1) A factory can return anything. Even `.factory("myVal", function () { return "Hello, world!"; })` is a valid factory. (2) you can expose anything on the return object and then manipulate it downstream as it will be the reference to the returned object that gets passed about.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Yes, I explained myself poorly! See this for a live example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/WZQaF/

Comment: @Julian Have you found out what happened in you example ? I have spent sometime to figure out. In fact, in the changePrivateVar, `this.privateVar` is undefined. because factory returns an instance created by the return block, and `this` refers to this instance. It is normal that `this.privateVar` is undefined. But if I delete `this`, it can find `privateVar`, because it finds it uppon the prototype chain. see http://jsfiddle.net/WZQaF/5/

Comment: @Qianyue I did figure this out kind of in the same direction as you are suggesting but now exactly: https://jsfiddle.net/lefok/t4s7qrjv/

Comment: @Julian In your jsfiddle, the data2 seems to be the same as data. I can't catch what is your intention to add the data2.

Comment: @Qianyue you would have if I had sent you the correct fiddle! (I forgot to click update) https://jsfiddle.net/lefok/eMUfT/4/

Comment: @Julian, thank you for your update. I rewrite de jsfiddle to have a more clear vision how the `this` works in your case. jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eMUfT/17/

Comment: @Qianyue That is beautiful, thanks! I think I finally got it!