# What five JavaScript concepts do I need to understand to be a good AngularJS developer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I'm used to coding on the server side (with server-side languages), and now I'm learning AngularJS.  That means I first need a good understanding of JavaScript.

If I don't have to time to fully learn JavaScript right now, what five JavaScript concepts would you recommend I learn first/well in order to be an effective AngularJS developer?

Comment: (I've thought AngularJS is opinionated enough that it requires strong understanding of JavaScript to be effective and truly master it, and that anything less doesn't do it justice, but if you're willing to accept some things as a bit magical, it's all good. :)  ). There really aren't that many moving parts to JavaScript ... the trick is how to utilize them and fit them together well. I'd read/skim through http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. the type system:  there are two fundamentally different kinds of values: primitives and objects.  Number, string, boolean, `null`, `undefined` are all primitives.  
   Array ( `[1,2,3]` ), object ( `{ prop1: value1, prop2: value2 }` ), and function are all objects.
2. [prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) – this is especially important when you attempt to databind in AngularJS to a primitive
3. array['syntax'] === array.syntax; array['$id'] === array.$id; array[*someExpression*] has no eqivalent "." notation
4. variable scope and assignment

   - a variable defined anywhere inside a function is visible *everywhere* inside that function
   - when a variable is assigned an object, it is assigned a *reference* (not a copy).  This becomes important in AngularJS when, e.g., you fetch JSON data from a server and you assign the results to a variable.  This resets the reference. Other variables (say in your controller) that point to the old reference continue to point to the old reference. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265565/angularjs-promise-is-resolved-before-data-is-loaded/12287364#12287364))
5. closures – these are very useful when defining AngularJS services ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904891/215945)) and when defining methods on a controller using `this` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699))

Also note that JavaScript is single-threaded!

Comment: Great list, I would add understanding of `this` keyword in context of JS language. Also prototypal inheritance has been mentioned but the general concepts around how to create object in JS and its OO nature is also important to understand.

Answer (score 3):

In my view you should get clarity on the following topics

1) **call by value vs call by reference in javascript**

Reason: because in angularJS we deal with a lot of objects. You will be clear     about their behaviour once you understand this

2) **Scope chain and IIFE(Immediately invocable function expression)**

Reason: When you work on an application using angularJS IIFEs play a major role    in manipulating your scope.

3) **Closures**

Reason: One of the most important javascript concept. If you see source code of a lot of famous libraries and frameworks built on javascript, they have used closures a lot. Closures will also help you understand how factories work in depth.

4) **Dependency Injection**

Reason: A javascript concept on which Angular JS is based

5) You can also go through some good style guides for AngularJS. For instance you can refer to this one: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide