# Reference to this within prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

I'm using this form to hide private functions of a class:
but `this` is always not what I expect.

```
function Person(){}

Person.prototype = (function(){

    console.log(this); // --> window, always

    function privateFunc(from){
        // private func always loses 'this' even if publicFunc had it
        console.log('private', from, this);
    }

    function publicFunc(from){
        // publicFunc has this only when called directly, not by timeout
        console.log('public', from, this);  
        privateFunc(from);
    }

    return {
        PublicFunc: publicFunc
    };

})/*.bind(???).*/();


var man = new Person();
man.PublicFunc('direct');
window.setTimeout(man.PublicFunc, 1, 'timeout');
```

I could solve it by binding the functions manually as such:

```
privateFunc.call(this, from);
window.setTimeout(man.PublicFunc.bind(man), 1, 'timeout');
```

But I do not like calling each private function with call. Is there another approach?

Comment: Set *this* in the call: `setTimeout(function('timeout'){man.PublicFunc()},1)`.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester let's ignore that functions are objects and focus on the fact that `Person.prototype = {PublicFunc: function publicFunc(from){...}};`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: why "this" inside the private function refers to the global scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9674288/1176601)

Comment: Side note: I do not need an explanation why this happens as suggested by `duplicate`. I need a way to capture `this` without manually `call`ing each function. AKA I need a different approach !?