# Does the following code create global variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function User (theName, theEmail) {
    this.name = theName;
    this.email = theEmail;
    this.quizScores = [];
    this.currentScore = 0;
    console.log(this.name);
}
var user1 = new User("Some Name", "tafd@sdf.com");
console.log(name);
```

It appears that the code above creates global variables.

Comment: What does the console log statement return? I would think nothing or undefined.  You want `console.log(user1.name);` I believe.

Comment: No) Remove this line  `console.log(this.name);` in User.

Comment: `name` should refer to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), which is predefined by the browser. It's possible that `User` modified the global property if it was at any point called without `new`. https://jsfiddle.net/75nLq957/

Comment: The console.log(name) returns "Some Name".

Comment: no it doesn't using only the code shown ... you are misinterpreting the log inside the function returning that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674252/javascript-why-this-inside-the-private-function-refers-to-the-global-scope

Answer (score -1):

Nope! Because your variables are declared inside a `function`.

Comment: But I thought if a variable is declared without the 'var' keyword no matter where, then it would be a global variable.

Comment: @TuanLe If you assign a previously unknown variable, that's when you create a global. The `this` keyword and its value are bound to the `function` for you. Property assignments, however, modify a specific object rather than any scopes (local or global).

Comment: Your function here constructs the objects. The newly created object instance, 'user1' can be accessed globally though.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Then why am I getting the same results from:

console.log(this.name) when executed inside the function

console.log(name);